# Mockito spy does not work

Tags: testing, mockito

I am trying to test my android project by Mockito.

But it seems that spy does not work as I think.
Isn't a spy object is equal to a real object?

when I try to call a method of spy object, testing result alway is AbstractMethodError(just as follows).

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
at com.google.dexmaker.mockito.InvocationHandlerAdapter$ProxiedMethod.isAbstract(InvocationHandlerAdapter.java)
at org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationImpl.callRealMethod(InvocationImpl.java:109)
at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.answers.CallsRealMethods.answer(CallsRealMethods.java:41)
at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:93)
at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:38)
at com.google.dexmaker.mockito.InvocationHandlerAdapter.invoke(InvocationHandlerAdapter.java:49)
at ArrayList_Proxy.add(ArrayList_Proxy.generated)
```

My test case:

```
public void testGetAllCountryKeywords_WithSpy(){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List spy = spy(list);
    spy.add("hi");

}
```

Here is the dependencies in my build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.+"
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.+"
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
}
```

Can someone give me some suggestion? I really have no idea. Thanks!

Comment: May be a bug between mockito 1.10 and dexmaker 1.2. Can you try forcing mockito 1.9.5 and see if that fixes it? https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/issues/detail?id=43

Comment: Same problem here. I was using 2.0.7-beta. Using version 1.9.5 sorts it.

Comment: @SkinnyJ After I changed the version to 1.9.5, spy works! Thanks!

Comment: @SandyLin you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the generic type, reference 'spy' proxy can not know its type

> public void testGetAllCountryKeywords_WithSpy(){
>       List list = new ArrayList<>();
>       List spy = spy(list);
>       spy.add("hi");
>
> }

Comment: Sorry. It seems that this is not the reason causing this error. I try to add the generic type, but the spy still doesn't work.

Comment: @TobeyLin what exactly the error that you are getting

Comment: Just as same as "abstract method not implemented"